# Camel TypeConverters auto-loading issue

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-quickfix

I have a pretty weird issue, while running my application in slightly different ways. When I start the app in the IDE(which is a classic console application with camel), it loads 176 Type Converters (as I see from the logs). When I try to start it via `java -jar`, it loads 172 Type Converters and I have following error while trying to launch the routes:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a suitable setter for property: sessionID as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang
>   .String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: quickfix.SessionID with value *BLAH*

Obviously, it cannot find a converter for the camel-quickfix module. All of the jars are double-checked and a `missing jar` is not likely to be the cause. Do you have any idea - how can I check the list of converters that are being loaded and how to fix that?

Comment: If you see @Claus Ibsen passing around, please tell him to stop by :)

Comment: If you repackage the camel JARs into a fat/uber JAR then see this FAQ - http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-a-big-uber-jar.html

Comment: That's what I actually have.. I packaged it via shade plugin and that's the current showstopper for me.

Comment: Oh, there is a bunch of new transformers over there.. I will check it out. Thanks!